# Offset Management - Confluent JDBC Connector in query mode

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

As per the confluent documentation, when we use the query mode, we have to do the offset management. As per my understanding, we need to keep track of the last updated timestamp and pass it in the where clause when we restart the program each time. Could anyone confirm if the understanding is correct? Appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both - you can still set the timestamp and incrementing mode in addition to the query. it will simply add a where statement based on timestamp.column.name and/or incrementing.column.name field. You can even use a subquery if your query needs a where statement

As an example you could set your query to: select * from (select apples from tree where color = green) as subquery

with the timestamp.column.name set to ripedate the sql kafka will execute is:

select * from (select apples from tree where color = green) as subquery where ripedate > offsetdate